# Understanding the Windows recycle bin

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

When I delete a large folder it takes time for it to be put into the recycle bin. And when I move that item back to where it was, it seems instant. I would like a deeper understanding on how this is possible.

Comment: There is more computational work to be done when moving to the bin that there is to restore it to the original location

Answer (score 1):

Moving any item into the recycling bin is only a temporary placement for your file to be.
It's almost the same as moving files between different folders, which will take more time.

When you put a file into a the bin, and restore the file back into the previous directory, it already has a remembrance of where it was in your drive, therefore it will restore quickly. However with a drive, it never has to worry that the file will be deleted, unlike the bin, so it will never have to remember it's old directory.

I hope this helps.